# Alternative solutions to $n^2+n = k^2+k + 2kn$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations

Consider this equation:

$n^2+n = k^2+k + 2kn$

I want to find the set of non-negative integer n,k that satisfies the equation.

I tried to write $n$ as $k$ by solving the equation with $n$ as root results in:
$n = {2k - 1 + \sqrt{8k^2 + 1} \over 2}$

With $8k^2+1$ as a square number, I found the series of $k$ by [pell equation](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/triSquare.shtml): $k_i = 6k_{i-1} - k_{i-2}$ , and thus $n$ can be deduced from there.

However there is a different solution, one can write:

$k_i = 2n_{i-1} + k_{i-1} + 1$

$n_i = 2k_i + n_{i-1}$

($n_0 = 0, k_0 = 0$)

Which I can't figure out how to get there. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $n^2+n=k^2+k+2kn$ may be rewritten as
$$[1]\ \ \ [2(n-k)+1]^2-8k^2=1,$$
which is a Pell equation of the simple type with 1 on the right side, all of whose solutions are obtained on writing $(3+\sqrt{8})^i=a_i+b_i\sqrt{8}.$
In this we have $2(n_i-k_i)+1=a_i$ and $k_i=b_i$

The recursion rule for the $a_i,b_i$ is obtained using
$$(a_{i-1}+b_{i-1}\sqrt{8})\cdot (3+\sqrt{8})=a_i+b_i\sqrt{8},$$
giving recursions $a_i=3a_{i-1}+8b_{i-1}$ and $b_i=a_{i-1}+3b_{i-1}.$
We now have to restate these recursions in terms of the variables $n_i,k_i$ of the original equation. Note that always $k_i=b_i$, and that from $a_i=2(n-k)+1$ we can recover $n_i$ as $n_i=(a_i+2k_i-1)/2.$

Now the recursion for $k_i$ is the easier of the two, since from the above:

$$k_i=b_i=a_{i-1}+3b_{i-1}=\\ 
[2n_{i-1}-2k_{i-1}+1]+3k_{i-1}=2n_{i-1}+k_{i-1}+1.$$
Thus $k_i=2n_{i-1}+k_{i-1}+1$ in agreement with the recursion for $k_i$ mentioned in the question of the post.

To show the other recurrence for the $n_i$ it will help to rewrite the version given in the question of the recurrence, quote:

> $k_i = 2n_{i-1} + k_{i-1} + 1$
>
> $n_i = 2k_i + n_{i-1}$
>
> ($n_0 = 0, k_0 = 0$)

by substituting for $k_i$ in the second relation its value from the first relation, obtaining:

$k_i = 2n_{i-1} + k_{i-1} + 1,$

$n_i = 5n_{i-1} + 2k_{i-1}+2.$

In this rewritten form, both relations refer from the present pair $n_i,k_i$ to the previous solution pair $n_{i-1},k_{i-1}.$

Now for $n_i$ we have the equations

$n_i=((a_i)+2(k_i)-1)/2 = ([3a_{i-1}+8k_{i-1}]+2[2n_{i-1}+k_{i-1}+1]-1)/2,$

where in the last parenthesis we used our above value for $k_i$. Now we can replace on the rightmost side  $a_{i-1}$ by its definition as $2n_{i-1}-2k_{i-1}+1$ and simplify algebraically, arriving at $n_i=5n_{i-1}+2k_{i-1}+2.$ This matches the rewritten recursion for $n_i$ (as noted above, in terms of $n_{i-1},k_{i-1}$) in the question of the post.

Comment: @iKid : I can fill this answer out if you reply and say what you are looking for. I couldn't tell whether you were looking for a way to get the other family of solutions, or were looking to set up the recursive formula for it.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get to the other solution. I suspect there is one method to solve this type of question resulting in a recursive formular. I still can't figure out how to get to there from your explanation.

Comment: @iKid -- Please have a look at my answer above, which I have completely re-written, and which has a step-by-step explanation of the recursions you ask about for $n_i$ and $k_i$. Note that this is actually all the solutions, and that if your approach were pushed through it would wind up with exactly these equations for $n_i$ and $k_i$. So there are *not* two different families of solutions as I had thought before.

Comment: Thank you! This is a truly beautiful way to apply pell !